# How to correctly use gdal_grid in a Python script

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-grid

I have a Python script to run `gdal_grid` using the subprocess command at the moment with certain parameters defined as variables earlier in the script

```
subprocess.call(f'gdal_grid -a nearest:radius1={cell_size}:radius2={cell_size}:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -txe {txextent} -tye {tyextent} -tr {resolution} -zfield z {shapefile} {output_file}.tif')
```

It works perfectly and the raster produced is exactly as intended. However, I've decided rather than use the `subprocess` method that it would be better practice to use `Gdal.Grid` as intended for Python.

So far I have this

```
rasterDs = gdal.Grid(gridded_raster, 
                     shapefile, 
                     format='GTiff',
                     algorithm='nearest:radius1={cell_size}:radius2={cell_size}:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0', 
                     outputType = 'GDT_Float32',
                     zfield='z')
rasterDs.FlushCache()
```

But I'm wondering, how do I provide the `-tye and -txe` along with `-tr` in order to ensure I get the exact same results? I can't seem to find them in the documentation https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#GridOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your `gdal_grid` options directly to `gdal.Grid()` as a string, including the `-tr` arg.

```py
options = f"-txe {xmin} {xmax} -tye {ymin} {ymax} -tr {cellsize} {cellsize} -ot Float32 -l grid -a nearest:radius1={cellsize}:radius2={cellsize}:angle=0.0:nodata=0.0"
rasterDs = gdal.Grid(gridded_raster, shapefile, options=options)
```

From the doc:

```sh
Grid(destName, srcDS, **kwargs)
    etc...
    Keyword arguments are :
      options --- return of gdal.GridOptions(), string or array of strings <-- note "string" means a gdal_grid commandline string
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an option to set `-tr`. I could be wrong.
However, you could get the correct resolution by calculating the raster `width` and `height` in pixels form the bounding box coordinates. For setting `-tye` and `-txe` use the `outputBounds=[ulx, uly, lrx, lry]`. Then using the bounds, calculate the raster size using something like

```
minx = ulx
maxx = lrx
miny = lry
maxy = uly
pixel_size = 10 # User specific

width = maxx-minx
height = maxy-miny

cols = width/pixel_size
rows = height/pixel_size
```

It might be necessary to `ceil` the width/height and/or cols/rows. Note, `cols` and `rows` will be the array sizes in pixels used to specify `width` and `height`.

```
rasterDs = gdal.Grid(gridded_raster, 
                     shapefile, 
                     format='GTiff',
                     algorithm='nearest:radius1={cell_size}:radius2={cell_size}:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0', 
                     outputType = 'GDT_Float32',
                     zfield='z',
                     outputBounds=[ulx, uly, lrx, lry],
                     width=cols,
                     height=rows)
```